# Generic Array in Java the right way

Tags: java, arrays, generics

How can i create a generic array in java, the right way?

```
T[] buffer = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
```

Would it better to create a new generic collection and then cast it?

Comment: that *is* the right way. What do you mean a generic collection and than cast it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a generic list:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Or check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/5251647)

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this

```
final T[] a = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **newInstance** method that offer *Array* class, but it require the Class of type.

The only solution that i see is create a *Object* array and then cast it to T[]

```
T[] array = (T[])Array.newInstance(Object.class, size);
```